# Django login from in modal window

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-crispy-forms

I have a login form and I want to put in modal window in header.

Urls.py

```
url(r'^account/login/$', appuser_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'account/login/index.html', form_class = appuser_forms.LoginForm, target_url = LOGIN_TARGET_URL)),
```

views.py

```
class LoginView(ResendEmailToUsersMixin, AjaxFormView):

    def process_form(self, request, form):
        data = form.cleaned_data

        a = AppUserCredential.objects.select_related('appuser').filter(
                data1 = data['email_address'],
                credential_type = AppUserCredential.CREDENTIAL_TYPES.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
                appuser__status = AppUser.STATUS_TYPES.Active
            ).first()

        force_error = False
        if a is None:
            response = self.resend_email_to_users(data = data)
            if response is not None:
                return response
            #If no email exists force the error and don't check the password
            force_error = True

        if force_error or not a.check_password(data['password']):
            return AjaxErrorResponse(code="login_error", title="Username or Password Error", message="The username or password you have provided don&#8217;t match our records. Please check your entries and try again.")

        a.appuser.login(request)
```

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(AjaxForm):
    email_address = forms.EmailField(label = "Email Address", required = True, max_length = 100,
                    widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'email@domain.com', 'autocomplete':'off'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label = "Password", required = True, max_length = 100,
                    widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Password', 'autocomplete':'off'}))

    def setup_form_helper(self, helper):
        helper.form_id = 'login_form'
        helper.layout = Layout(
            'email_address',
            'password',
            Div(
                Submit('submit', 'Login', css_class='btn btn-primary'),
                css_class="form-group text-center"
                ),
            HTML('<p class="pull-right light-top-bottom-padding"><a href="/account/forgot-password" title="Forgot Password">Forgot Password?</a></p>')
            )
```

/templates/account/login/index.html

```
...
{% crispy form form.helper %}
...
```

I have created modal window in `/templates/layouts/header.html` 
How can I put `{% crispy form form.helper %}` in the modal window? 
Thanks.

**UPD1:**
If I put `{% crispy form form.helper %}` in header.html I got the error

> VariableDoesNotExist at / Failed lookup for key [form] in u'[{\'False\': False, \'None\': None, \'True\': True},

**UPD2:**
Modal form:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="text-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">login</a>

        <div id="login" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <header class="section-title text-center normal-top-bottom-padding">
                            <h1>Login</h1>
                        </header>
                    </div>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

Link to login should be in every page.

Comment: Just render the form inside the modal window template area. How have you created that modal window? Please post the code.

Comment: It is just bootsrap modal. I have updated my post @C14L

Comment: Where did you get `AjaxFormView`` from?

Comment: It is a wrapper from previous developer @BurhanKhalid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to display the form in all pages, you need to add the `form` (better call it `login_form` so it doesn't conflict with other forms you may have) to every View's context.

To avoid doing that repeatedly in all Views, Django has Context Processors. You include them in `settings.py`'s `TEMPLATES` variable. Example

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    ...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            ...
            'myapp.context_processors.add_my_login_form',
        ],
    }]
```

Then, create a file called `context_processors.py` and add the `add_my_login_form()` function in there. The function returns the `login_form` to the request context of all requests.

```
def add_my_login_form(request):
    return {
        'login_form': LoginForm(),
    }
```

Since you are rendering the form in every page, it maybe good to use template caching.

Comment: But what next? How should I use add_my_login_form() and how to configure url pattern?

Comment: Thanks! I think it works. I just got an error 405 (method not allowed) when I try to login.

Comment: Yes, it works when I call modal window on page mysite.com/account/login, but 405 error if i call modal window and try to login on other pages.

Comment: Make sure your `<form>` actually posts to `/account/login`, i.e. it has `<form action="/account/login" ...>`, and not an empty `action=""` like forms usually have. Because you need to actually post it to your login view.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have added action to crispy form and all works great.