# Django modal loginview - error: "form" should contain a valid Django Form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to do my login with bootstrap modal so it can be accessed from any page through my navbar with the login-popup. 
The problem now is how do I pass that form on so all of the pages can access it? At the moment I get this error:

> BootstrapError at /
>
> Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form.

Instead of using a seperate page for my login form I have now this:

login3.html

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

        <div id="div-forms">
          <form id="login-form" action="{% url 'login3' %}" method="post" 
                enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="modal-body">
              {% bootstrap_form form %}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              {% buttons %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
              {% endbuttons %}
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

View:

```
class Login3View(NextUrlMixin, RequestFormAttachMixin, FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'accounts/login3.html'
    success_url = '/'
    default_next = '/'
```

And then I'm simply including the template login3.html together with my navbar so the form gets loaded at every page.

I saw at a different question an answer from C14L ([Django login from in modal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982412/django-login-from-in-modal-window)) that looked promising   but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks for any tipps.

---

Update: 
here's the LoginForm

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        request = self.request
        data = self.cleaned_data
        email = data.get("email")
        password = data.get("password")

        qs=User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
            #user email is registered, check active/email activation
            not_active = qs.filter(is_active=False)
            if not_active.exists():
                #not active, check email activation
                ....
```

Comment: Your `LoginForm` is probably not a *subclass* of `Form`. Can you share the (relevant parts of the) `LoginForm`?

Comment: Updated the question with the LoginForm, Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have added a `request` parameter to your `LoginForm`:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):

    # ...

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You need to *patch* the `get_form_kwargs` function such that you can add a `request` parameter when initializing the form:

```
class Login3View(NextUrlMixin, RequestFormAttachMixin, FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'accounts/login3.html'
    success_url = '/'
    default_next = '/'

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Hey,I thought it worked but ended up being the same error again as soon as I include the login3.html in my landing page. Can it be related that the context of that view/or others are not having the form in there context? Or should it worked from my Login3View alone?

Comment: @Tobstar: of course it only works for `Login3View` (and subclasses), how would the logic defined in this class automagically get transferred to other classes? You need to patch it in all views that use the form, or you can define a mixin that is then inherited in the affected views.

Comment: Must have been a misunderstanding then since I did ask in the question that I need it to be accessable from any page cause it is within my navbar/a modal popup. Patching it in all the views doesn't sound good to me but would you have any idea how to attack it with the mixin that gets inherited? It will essentially effect all views.

Comment: @Tobstar: hold on, you want to render the *same* form on all views? That is *not* where such views are for. The idea of a `FormView` is to create/edit/... a certain record. Typically something all `FormView`s have different forms. Furthermore if your app would need an extra form (for example one where one creates a post), then this would result in a lot of "hacking" into the formview. Data that is 'constant' across all pages belong in a *context processor*, not in a view.

Comment: Ok so now we are back to square one. In my question I refer to a different stackoverflow post answer from C14L who mentions the context processor but I was not able to get it work the way he described it. I might have done something wrong on the way since it wasn't 100% written out or I thought I had a different case.

Comment: Well the only thing you would have to change to the linked answer (I think) is that you construct the `LoginForm` with `'login_form': LoginForm(request=request),` instead.