# Django: Registration form on modals available on multiple pages

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have the following scenario:

- I have a navbar available on all the pages of my website.
- The navbar has a button that opens a modal for registering.
- The modal has a form. The corresponding Django form is injected via a Context Processors (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982412/django-login-from-in-modal-window)).

My problem, however, is that I don't know how to process the request (registration or login) in such a way that I don't need to have this logic repeated on every view.

Comment: let us say you have a `base.html` and your extend this to all other pages and then in this template(`base.html`) put the modal there outside the `block`.then it will be available everywhere.and if you do not want to do this for some reasons you can create a `context_processors`  in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings.py

Comment: @amadousow My issue is with the view, though. The view that should process the request and register/login the user. I don't want to have that logic on every view.

Comment: if the modal is available everywhere then it should work also for views,except if you have an argument in the url but i do not think for registering/login you need any arguments in the url,or am i missing something ?

Comment: @amadousow The issue is the logic that register/login the user in the view. In every view that has the modal (all) now I need to add the logic to check for the form, authenticate the user, etc. It works but I would like not to repeat the same logic everywhere on my site. :)

Comment: look here is how you can do it.you first create a `context_processors` for forms (log/register) by using get method and in these forms just add `method="post"` and `action="---the-url - of -login-or-register--"` after that just create your views  for handling the forms this will work.you do not need to repeat your views at all.have you tried this ?

Comment: @amadousow It works! :) If you want to write a response I can select it as the correct one.