# How to open django login form in a modal window?

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

How can i open dJango modal form in a modal popup window?

```
from django_base.forms import User_registration_form

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data = request.POST)
```

Comment: https://github.com/trco/django-bs4-modal-login

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django login from in modal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982412/django-login-from-in-modal-window)

Comment: i tried to implement that solution Jyothish but it seem my knowledge is not enough because i run into many errors, it seems is not compatible with last versions of python/django